# How to implement navigation drawer with new Material Design

Tags: android

How to implement navigation drawer with Pic  in new Material Design

Comment: Look this : http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Answer (score 0):

I think if you put your these question on Google you will never get -ve Points.
I think these link may help you i also used these link to develop that kind of task. 
[Link](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html)
And you will get many more examples, Just Google it.